# Add Class to Knockout Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to create a knockout component which will show notifications at the bottom of the screen.  This currently works just fine, but I had intended to be able to add more animation to the notifications.  Ideally what I would like to do is have the notification immediately start to fade over 5 seconds.  After 5 seconds, it would then be removed from the notification array and thus the element deleted.  However if the user mouses over the notification, the fadeout sequence should be stopped completely.  Currently I do not see how I can access the dom element of the notification in this way however. Can anyone recommend a solution?

**HTML Binding**

```
<div class="notification-container" data-bind="foreach: notificationArray">
    <notification params="data: $data"></notification>
</div>
```

**Notification JS**

```
appViewModel.notificationArray = ko.observableArray([]);

appViewModel.setNotification = function( message ){
    appViewModel.notificationArray.push({
        'message':message
    })
};
```

**Component JS**

```
ko.components.register('notification', {
    viewModel: function(params) {

        var data = params.data;

        this.message = data.message || null;
        this.timer = null;

        this.removeNotification = function() {
            appViewModel.notificationArray.remove(data);
        };

        this.timer =  ( function(self) {
            return setTimeout(function() {
                self.removeNotification();
            }, 5000);
        })(this);

        this.hover = function () {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        };

        this.restart = function() {
            this.timer = ( function(self) {
                return setTimeout(function() {
                    self.removeNotification();
                }, 5000);
            })(this);
        }

    },
    template: '<div class="notification show-notification" data-bind="event: { mouseover: hover, fastClick: hover, mouseout: restart }">'
        +'<div class="notifications-close clickable right" data-bind="fastClick: removeNotification"><span class="icon icon-x"></span></div>'
        +'<div class="notification-text" data-bind="html: message"></div>'
        +'</div>'
});
```

**----- Update to show completed code -----**

The end result for the completed code is that the notification will now bounce in from off screen, and immediately start to fade away over 5 seconds.  The fadeout/removal from array will be stopped if the notification is clicked on (I removed the mouse hover events due to mobile support).  Hope this is helpful for someone else.

**HTML Binding** - same as above

**Notification JS** - same as above

**Custom Binding for fading**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.fadeVisible = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).height();    //need to trigger re-paint in order for transition to fire
        $(element).addClass('show-notification');
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        $(element).stop();
        ko.unwrap(value) ? $(element).fadeIn(0) : $(element).fadeOut(5000);
    }
};
```

**Updated Component JS**

```
ko.components.register('notification', {
    viewModel: function(params) {

        var data = params.data;

        this.message = data.message || null;
        this.timer = null;
        **this.paused = ko.observable(false);**

        this.removeNotification = function() {
            appViewModel.notificationArray.remove(data);
        };

        this.timer =  ( function(self) {
            return setTimeout(function() {
                self.removeNotification();
            }, 5000);
        })(this);

        this.pause = function () {
            **this.paused(true);**
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        };

    },
    template: '<div class="notification clickable" data-bind="fadeVisible: paused, fastClick: pause">'
        +'<div class="notifications-close clickable right" data-bind="fastClick: removeNotification"><span class="icon icon-x"></span></div>'
        +'<div class="notification-text" data-bind="html: message"></div>'
        +'</div>'
});
```

**Relevant CSS**

```
.notification {
    visibility: hidden;
    max-height: 5.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    border: 1px solid rgb(72, 72, 72);
    background: white;
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 15px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-transform: translate(100%, 0);
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1.20, 0, 1.20);
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1.20, 0, 1.20),transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 1.20, 0, 1.20);
}

.show-notification {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a custom binding handler to handle the fading. You could, if you wanted, handle the removal from the binding handler as well, but I can't decide whether that's a good idea.

```js
ko.components.register('notification', {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    var data = params.data;

    this.message = data.message || null;
    var timer = null;

    this.removeNotification = function() {
      appViewModel.notificationArray.remove(data);
    };

    this.hover = function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    this.restart = function() {
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        self.removeNotification();
      }, 5000);
    }
    this.restart();

  },
  template: '<div class="notification show-notification" data-bind="event: { mouseover: hover, fastClick: hover, mouseout: restart }, fadeOut:true">' + '<div class="notifications-close clickable right" data-bind="fastClick: removeNotification"><span class="icon icon-x"></span></div>' + '<div class="notification-text" data-bind="html: message"></div>' + '</div>'
});

ko.bindingHandlers.fadeOut = {
  init: function(el) {
    $(el).fadeOut(5000);
    $(el).hover(function() {
        $(el).stop().fadeIn(0);
      },
      function() {
        $(el).fadeOut(5000);
      });
  }
}

appViewModel = {};
appViewModel.notificationArray = ko.observableArray([{
  message: 'Hi there'
}]);

appViewModel.setNotification = function(message) {
  appViewModel.notificationArray.push({
    'message': message
  })
};


ko.applyBindings(appViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="notification-container" data-bind="foreach: notificationArray">
  <notification params="data: $data"></notification>
</div>
```

Comment: I have implemented a solution based on your suggestion.  I have edited my OP to show the new solution.